# Why UUID generate nulls instead of uniqe ID

Tags: java, spring, entity, uniqueidentifier

I have service which is getting values from api and mapping it by model mapper to the unified entity.
The problem is that UUID is not working. I am getting null instead of any string id (I had to change name of if for "uniqueIdentifier" becouse objects from api had "id" field).

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "unifiedOffers")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UnifiedOfferEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String uniqueIdentifier;
    private String companyName;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String title;
    private LocalDateTime posted;
    private String url;
}
```

Endpoint for tests:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String getOffers() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<UnifiedOfferEntity> result = jobFinderService.getAllOffers();
    for (UnifiedOfferEntity unifiedOfferEntity : result) {
        System.out.println(unifiedOfferEntity.getUniqueIdentifier() + " " + unifiedOfferEntity.getTitle() + " " + unifiedOfferEntity.getUrl());
    }
    unifedOfferRepository.saveAll(result);
    return String.valueOf(result.size());
}
```

In that foreach I am getting values like for example:

```
null JavaDeveloper anyLinkUrl
```

so only UUID is not generating ids.

Comment: Why should there be ids... Those are generated when inserting in the database, so after the call to `saveAll`.

Comment: Ok, so I completely not understand that process., when I am doing saveAll it throws "java.sql.SQLException: Field 'unique_identifier' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: Well for starters you don't have a transaction, the code that is in your controller should be in a service method marked with `@Transactional`. Also make sure you have the proper `@Id` annotation on the field (the one from JPA and not from Spring Data). I also don't really get why you couldn't use `id` (although that doesn't really matter).

Answer (score -1):

have you defined the underline class to implement uuid generator?
in a similar case I used the follwing code that accepts a parameter "rangeName" you can remove

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="intRange")
@GenericGenerator(name="intRange",
        strategy = "imp.framework.jerpBridge.IntRangeGenerator" ,
        parameters = {
                @Parameter( name = "rangeName", value="DOCMA01")
        })
public String nrDocumento;
```

where

```
public class IntRangeGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

     public IntRangeGenerator(String rangeName) {
        this.rangeName = rangeName;
     }


    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
          return "generated ID";
     }
```

Comment: THat is not needed as `uuid` is a magic name in JPA to map to a generator for UUIDs. So you don't need to explicitly state the strategy (nor would it work and fail with an error if the magic name wasn't recognized!).